# What's the most idiomatic Rust way to modify an optional element of a Vec conditionally?

Tags: rust, idioms, borrow-checker

I'm confused about the best way to write the following very common kind of code:

```
let old_best = best_by_pos[y][x].as_ref();
if old_best.is_none() || &new_cost < old_best.unwrap() {
    best_by_pos[y][x] = Some(new_cost.clone());
}
```

This is just a code sample, but it illustrates the problem.

`best_by_pos` is a `Vec<Vec<Option<BigInt>>>`; when we find a new possibility for the best cost at that point, we want to (a) check if the new cost is better than the old cost, and (b) if it is, update the vector.

The problem is that `old_best` borrows `best_by_pos` immutably, and that borrow persists until the end of the scope. This prevents the mutation inside the if block. Ideally I'd like to free up `old_best` immediately after the test but it's not clear how to do that.

There is a very ugly way to do it -- make a deeper scope which does the test and exposes a boolean, then doing a conditional on that. This is functional but unpleasant.

Alternately, I can make a helper method which does the comparison (and frees up its borrows when it terminates), which looks cleaner, but still feels bloated.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `old_best` a mutable reference into the vector, and write to it in the assignment. This also allows you to avoid indexing the vector again:

```
let old_best = &mut best_by_pos[y][x];
if old_best.is_none() || &new_cost < old_best.as_ref().unwrap() {
    *old_best = Some(new_cost.clone());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to stay with a `Vec`, something like this avoids any explicit `unwrap`s:

```
let slot = &mut best_by_pos[y][x];
let is_better = slot.as_ref().map_or(true, |old_cost| &new_cost < old_cost);
if is_better {
    *slot = Some(new_cost.clone());
}
```

This still holds a mutable borrow into the vector, so you'd need to wrap it in a scope.

Another possibility is some less-common pattern syntax:

```
match best_by_pos[y][x] {
    ref mut entry @ None => *entry = Some(new_cost.clone()), 
    Some(ref mut entry) => {
        if &new_cost < entry {
            *entry = new_cost.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Guessing, based on the usage of `Option` inside the vector, I'd encourage you to *not use a `Vec`*. Instead, a `HashMap` can better represent the concept of a sparse array. In addition, you get to use the Entry API:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;

let mut best_by_pos: HashMap<(usize, usize), BigInt> = Default::default();

match best_by_pos.entry((x, y)) {
    Entry::Vacant(e) => {
        e.insert(new_cost.clone());
    }
    Entry::Occupied(mut e) => {
        if &new_cost < e.get() {
            e.insert(new_cost.clone());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Option<T>` implements `Ord` for all types `T`, which implement `Ord`, in such a way that `None` is less than `Some(v)` for any `v`. You can write your code like this:

```
if best_by_pos[y][x].is_none() || Some(&new_cost) < best_by_pos[y][x].as_ref() {
    best_by_pos[y][x] = Some(new_cost.clone());
}
```

Taking into account interjay answer, it can also be written as

```
let cost = &mut best_by_pos[y][x];
if cost.is_none() || Some(&new_cost) < cost.as_ref() {
    *cost = Some(new_cost.clone());
}
```

Comment: You didn't really fix OP's problem: You had to write `best_by_pos[y][x]` multiple times to avoid the borrow, but OP borrowed the value precisely to avoid doing that. Using `Option`'s implementation of `PartialOrd` is an orthogonal issue.

Comment: Technically, the stated problem is the borrow that lasts too long and code bloat. `Ord` implementation for `Option<T>` is not orthogonal for the second part.

Comment: It is 100% unrelated to OP's question which was about avoiding a problem with the borrow checker. It would make a good comment though. By the way, you are missing a `clone()`. And if you add the `clone()` to the first line, it will hurt the code's performance relative to the original.

Comment: Fair point. The point about `clone()` that is. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: So now the only thing your answer changes is remove one `unwrap` and add an extra `Some`. What's the benefit exactly? How does this make the code less bloated?

Comment: The benefit is to know the tools at one's disposal. But this conversation becomes unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` can be quite concise, if you use other `Entry` methods, `and_modify` and `or_insert`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut best_pos: HashMap<(usize, usize), f64> = Default::default();
    let newprice = 60.0;

    best_pos
        .entry((1, 2))
        .and_modify(|e| *e = e.min(newprice))
        .or_insert(newprice);
}
```